# Does breast milk make vessels non-kosher or milchig?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

I understand that breast milk is kosher only for babies and is traif for adults. But does breast milk make other vessels non-kosher? For example, if I put a spoon, knife or fork in the breast milk, or cook the breast milk n a pot, can I use it for myself?

If these vessels are not traif at all, are they milchig or parve?

Comment: IINM breast milk is not milchig, could make a cheeseburger out of it (but why would you want to?) [_citation needed_]

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=64732

Comment: @GershonGold - Many links, such as the one you posted are blocked by my browser. Can you extract and post or summarize the main idea?

Comment: @DanF, the link is a Teshuvah that says mother's milk is Mutar for adults to drink (with two circumstantial exceptions, but the basic law is Heter).

Comment: @SethJ - OK. Then, my assumption that it is traif is wrong. I had heard from a few rabbanim that adults are not allowed to drink breast milk at all. Maybe, there are other opinions. Personally, I don't recall what it tastes like, but a 3 year old once told me it tastes a lot like "the milk mommy gives me in my bowl of Cheerios". Funny, but I still can't figure out what the kid means :-)

Comment: It's all kosher and pareve.

Comment: @DanF, so, one of the restrictions in the ruling above (which is really straight out of the Shulhan 'Aruch) is that it is Kosher if it is in a vessel. Basically, an adult is not permitted to nurse; I cannot recall offhand, and am unable to look up right now, if it's considered disgusting, and the prohibition of Bal TiShaketzu applies, or if it's something else.